# Storing subclasses in superclass vector

Tags: c++, vector, subclass, superclass

I'm trying to build a sequencer for the AccidentalNoise library, where a user can generate an XML file describing various types of noise layers, and get a result. I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how inheritance works in C++.

Unfortunately not all methods of the subclasses (*CImplicitSphere* in this case) are defined in the superclass (*CImplicitModuleBase*) as such, I had no success initializing the vector value immediately (*CImplicitSphere.setCenter()* is a good example). This is what I've got so far:

```
std::vector<anl::CImplicitModuleBase *> layers;

anl::CImplicitSphere tmp;

tmp.setCenter(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);

layers.push_back(&tmp);

value = layers.back()->get(0.0,0.0,0.0);
```

But I'm getting a "pure virtual method called" error - and that's about where I'm stuck - do I need to type-cast? There's some discussion about that - but it seems to suggest it's a bad idea.

Is there a better way of structuring my code so that I can initialize the *CImplicitSphere* directly in the layers vector, and point to the subclass methods as I go?

Full source:

```
void ScalarTerrain::setupAccidentalNoise() {
printf("Making an array of noise functions\n");
std::vector<anl::CImplicitModuleBase *> layers;

try {
    printf("Getting data for next layer\n");
    pugi::xml_node layer = terrainData.child("layer");

    if(strcmp(layer.attribute("type").value(), "sphere") == 0) {
        printf("Layer is a sphere building a temp layer\n");
        anl::CImplicitSphere tmp;

        tmp.setCenter(
            layer.child("center").attribute("x").as_double(),
            layer.child("center").attribute("y").as_double(),
            layer.child("center").attribute("z").as_double(),
            layer.child("center").attribute("u").as_double(),
            layer.child("center").attribute("v").as_double(),
            layer.child("center").attribute("w").as_double()
        );

        layers.push_back(&tmp);
    }
     else {
        printf("Layer type not found\n");
    }


} catch (char * exception) {
    printf("Exception raised: %s\n", exception);
}
try {
    for(int z = 0; z < z_chunk; z++) {
        for(int y = 0; y < y_chunk; y++) {
            for(int x = 0; x < x_chunk; x++) {
                value = layers.back()->get(
                    (double) x/x_chunk * 2, 
                    (double) y/y_chunk * 2, 
                    (double) z/z_chunk * 2
                );

                tc.values[x][y][z] = value;

                if(value < -0.5) tc.materials[x][y][z] = 0;
                else if (value < 0) tc.materials[x][y][z] = 1;
                else if (value < 0.5) tc.materials[x][y][z] = 2;
                else tc.materials[x][y][z] = 3;
            }
        }
    }
} catch (char * exception) {
    printf("Exception raised: %s\n", exception);
}
}
```

Comment: The vector part is not highly important - any collection of objects will do.

Comment: According to the [online docs](http://accidentalnoise.sourceforge.net/implicit.html#Sphere) the derived class (`CImplicitSphere`) doesn't provide an implementation of a pure virtual `get` method.  Why? I don't know, I don't use the library.  Also - you're adding the address of an automatic-storage variable to a vector.  Is this your intention?

Comment: I don't know - I come from a background of higher level languages, and throwing myself in the deep end is the only way I'm ever going to grok C++.

Comment: Could you post the full source file?

Comment: CImplicitSphere does indeed implement get() it seems the docs only show unique methods.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to work, and is not violently ugly:

```
void ScalarTerrain::setupAccidentalNoise() {
printf("Making an array of noise functions\n");
std::vector<anl::CImplicitModuleBase *> layers;
anl::CImplicitModuleBase * tmp;


//anl::CImplicitSphere thisLayer;

try {
    printf("Getting data for next layer\n");
    pugi::xml_node layer = terrainData.child("layer");

    if(strcmp(layer.attribute("type").value(), "sphere") == 0) {
        printf("Layer is a sphere building a temp layer\n");
        tmp = new anl::CImplicitSphere();

        dynamic_cast<anl::CImplicitSphere*>(tmp)->setCenter(
            layer.child("center").attribute("x").as_double(),
            layer.child("center").attribute("y").as_double(),
            layer.child("center").attribute("z").as_double(),
            layer.child("center").attribute("u").as_double(),
            layer.child("center").attribute("v").as_double(),
            layer.child("center").attribute("w").as_double()
        );

        layers.push_back(tmp);
    }
     else {
        printf("Layer type not found\n");
    }


} catch (char * exception) {
    printf("Exception raised: %s\n", exception);
}
try {
    printf("Iterating through blocks\n");

    for(int z = 0; z < z_chunk; z++) {
        for(int y = 0; y < y_chunk; y++) {
            for(int x = 0; x < x_chunk; x++) {
                printf("getting block value at %d %d %d\n",x,y,z);

                value = layers.back()->get(
                    (double) x/x_chunk * 2, 
                    (double) y/y_chunk * 2, 
                    (double) z/z_chunk * 2
                );

                tc.values[x][y][z] = value;

                if(value < -0.5) tc.materials[x][y][z] = 0;
                else if (value < 0) tc.materials[x][y][z] = 1;
                else if (value < 0.5) tc.materials[x][y][z] = 2;
                else tc.materials[x][y][z] = 3;
            }
        }
    }
} catch (char * exception) {
    printf("Exception raised: %s\n", exception);
}
}
```

Is this the "right" way of doing things or am I off the mark?

Comment: If you make `tmp` a `CImplicitSphere*` rather than a `CImplicitModuleBase*` you won't have to `dynamic_cast` it in order to `setCenter`, and a vector of pointers to the base class will still accept it.

Comment: This is just the beginning of the script - the idea is I loop through an if/else chain, create a new object in tmp (Could be CImplicitSphere, could be CImplicitFractal, could be CImplicitBasisFunction etc) configure it, possibly reference a previous one in vector (which looks like it may need to be a map) and drop it onto the collection.

Is continuously remaking CImplicitModuleBase objects on tmp going to lead me into trouble?